# Why my hook_filter not work in Drupal 6?

Tags: views, input-formats

I'm having a hard time trying to make my hook_filter work on Drupal 6.

Here's my filter function.

```
function arb_question_filter($op, $delta = 0, $format = -1, $text = '') {

  drupal_set_message($op);

  switch($op){

  case 'list':    
    return array(t('My filter name here'));

  case 'description':
    return t('Description my filter here');

  case 'settings':
    break;

  case 'no cache':
    return false;

  case 'prepare':
    return $text;

  case 'process':        
    return preg_replace("|\[support!\]|i", 'hello world', $text);

  default:
    return $text;   
  }
}
```

I can see my filter name on the filter option below the content textarea, but when I add my testing for example " this is a test [support!]"

When I view the content, it just show [support!], which is suppose to show "hello world" according to my filter.

I did put a drupal_set_message($op) on my hook filter, but it seems to only show "list" not process or prepare or the rest of the $op.

What I'm doing wrong?

Welcome your advice

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are only seeing 'list', I would make sure that your filter is added to an existing Input Format (check at `admin/settings/filters` and click on configure next to the appropriate input format) and also that all caches are cleared.  Sometimes if you start entering/coding a filter and it runs before you've got all the kinks worked out, the `case 'no cache'` gets in the way and stores the initial/wrong result.  Until you are sure of everything, you may want to change that to `return TRUE;` as well.

Comment: Thanks jimajamma for your reply to my question.  I just realized that my filter will only work when I logout. When I logout and view the contet I created, it seems the filter is working. If I login to my drupal site and create content, my filter will not work. I'm thinking about permission or role maybe?

Comment: Okay I now found the solution, I now found the check_markup() function..mmm no one mention this function to me :) Anyway in order to filter my content before output to the browser, I have to put my content inside check_markup($node->body)